# Update or edit nuxtjs app hosted on Zeit Now

Tags: nuxt.js, vercel

I have built an Nuxtjs app and hosted on zeit Now using CLI (not using github respository). So my question is what is the best way to update My app ?

Answer (score 1):

Update your app locally and push it to Now.

If your app is in a Git repo and that repo is linked to Now (through a GitHub or GitLab integration), when you push to the master branch, it will deploy your updates to Now.

If you're not using Git, you can install the `now` CLI via `npm` and then, from the project directory, run `now --prod` to do a production deployment or just `now` for a staging deployment.

Comment: Thank you for your reply . So will this command now --prod will update my current app ?

Comment: i am using Now CLI currently

Comment: Okk Thank you . I have also tried using Github and it's working nice